# Is there a recommended way to stream a cloudwatch logs on a backend API in real-time?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I want to execute multiple jobs in AWS Batch which produce job logs. I want a specific job log by streaming the log events from cloudwatch through a python API server to a frontend server. Is there any solution readily available for real-time stream of cloudwatch logs?

Comment: You'll have to call `get_log_events` over and over: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs/client/get_log_events.html